# Mojibake in the linux console

Tags: linux, fedora, fonts, encoding, symbols

There was no problem for five years. But when reinstalling Fedora from scratch, she reappeared again.

So, in the console (not the terminal) (Ctrl-Alt-F3, for example), Linux was displayed small squares instead Cyrillic symbols. `setfont` in which way I fixed it did not work earlier, deduced an error

```
couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Reading the FAQ on Fedora, I found that I need to install some fonts and set  it in vconsole.conf

```
KEYMAP="us"
FONT="ter-v16n"
```

Did not work. Then rebuilt `sudo dracut --- force` Instead of squares, mojibake appeared. If I run the command:

`sudo setfont ter-v16n`

Cyrillic appears, but only for a while. It is necessary to return to the GUI, and then back — the same mojibake.

1. It is strange that setfont without sudo causes an error and does not work. The guys from the chat say that they work without a root, and yes it was like that for me.
2. I can not understand why the font is reset when going to another console and returning back.